# Acces violation on va_arg

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I am trying to create a function that takes a variable number of matrix in parameters and multiply theses to a first one.
I can read a first one using `va_arg`, but the next call of `va_arg` will cause an access violation.

Here is how i declare my method :

```
template<class MType>
static CMatrice<MType> COperationsComplexesMatricesPassages::OCPChangementDeBase
   (CMatrice<MType> & MATVecteur, unsigned int uiNbMatricesPassages,
    CMatricePassage<MType> MAPMatrices...)
```

And here is how i call it :

```
COperationsComplexesMatricesPassages::OCPChangementDeBase(mat1, 2, matP1, matP2)
```

The exception appears on the first `va_arg` of the `for(...)` in the body of my method.
This is the code of my method:

```
unsigned int uiIndice;
unsigned int uiBaseArriveePrecedente;

va_list args;
va_start(args, MAPMatrices);

CMatrice<MType> MATResult(MATVecteur);
CMatricePassage<MType> MAPMatricePass = va_arg(args, CMatricePassage<MType>);

MATResult = MATResult * MAPMatricePass;

uiBaseArriveePrecedente = MAPMatricePass.MAPGetBaseArrivee();
for (uiIndice = 1; uiIndice < uiNbMatricesPassages; uiIndice++) {
    CMatricePassage<MType> MAPMatricePass2 = va_arg(args, CMatricePassage<MType>);
    if (uiBaseArriveePrecedente != MAPMatricePass2.MAPGetBaseDepart()) {
        CException EXCError(EXC_ChangementImpossible);
        throw EXCError;
    }
    uiBaseArriveePrecedente = MAPMatricePass2.MAPGetBaseArrivee();
    MATResult = MATResult * MAPMatricePass2;
}

return MATResult;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you exactly want obtain from your `OCPChangementDeBase()` method, anyway... maybe I'm wrong... but it seems to me that there are a couple of important points, regarding variadic functions, that you don't know.

(1) the old C variad syntax

```
void foo (int a, int b...)
```

doesn't mean that `b` is a variadic list of integer.

That declaration is equivalent (the last comma is optional) to

```
void foo (int a, int b, ...)
```

so, with both declarations, you have a `b` integer (a single `b` integer) and an unnamed list of variadic arguments.

So given you method

```
template<class MType>
static CMatrice<MType>
COperationsComplexesMatricesPassages::OCPChangementDeBase
   (CMatrice<MType> & MATVecteur, unsigned int uiNbMatricesPassages,
    CMatricePassage<MType> MAPMatrices...)
```

and calling it

```
COperationsComplexesMatricesPassages::OCPChangementDeBase(mat1, 2, matP1, matP2)
```

you have that

- `MATVecteur` become `mat1`
- `uiNbMatricesPassages` become `2`
- `MAPMatrices` become `matP1`
- the unnamed variadic list `...` become `matP2`

So, if you're expecting **two** arguments in the unnamed varidic list, you have only one and I'm not surprised that "the next call of va_arg will cause an access violation."

(2) the old C variadic syntax (`va_list`, `va_arg`, `va_start` based) remains available in C++ but, as far I know, works only for PODs (Plain Old Data) types.

So, as far I know, your code is UB (undefined bahaviour) because `matP2` (I suppose) isn't POD.

Fortunately C++ (starting from C++11) introduce variadic templates that are compatible also with not PODs types.

So, I suppose, you count write your method as follows or something similar

```
template <typename MType, typename ... MTs>
static auto COperationsComplexesMatricesPassages::OCPChangementDeBase
   (CMatrice<MType> & MATVecteur, MTs ... MAPMatrices)
 {
   auto MatResult { MatVectour };

   ( MatResult *= MapMatrices, ... ); // template folding; only from C++17

   return MatResult;
 }
```

You can also add some constraints (look for SFINAE) to impose that `MTs...` types are exactly (or, maybe better, convertible to) `CMatricePassage<MType>` (or another type, if you want).